# Do pointers to different types match the "common initial sequence" rule?

Tags: c, unions

If I have a union that contains pointers to different types of data, would it be legal to free malloced memory via a different field than the one it was assigned to?  Does it even match the "common initial sequence" rule?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int type;
    union {
        void *entries;
        long *long_entries;
        // etc
    } u;
} Bar;

int main (void) {
   Bar bar;
   bar.u.long_entries = malloc(6 * sizeof(long));
   free(bar.u.entries);
}
```

I'm inclined to say that this is legal, but I'm not entirely sure.

---

Considering the answers so far, I think I would have to change my code to something like this; which I expect is fully legal:

```
typedef struct {
    int type;
    void *entries;
} Bar;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Bar bar;
    bar.entries = malloc(6 * sizeof(long));
    // ...
    long *long_entries = bar.entries;
    long_entries[3] = 123;
    // ...
    free(bar.entries);
}
```

Comment: The C standard specifies that almost all pointers are implicitly convertible to or from `void *`, with pointers to functions as the only exception. ***But*** that is only for *conversion*. IIRC the C specification doesn't say that pointers really have to be the same, or even be of the same size.

Comment: With the above said, I doubt you find a modern system where it won't work, and where all pointers (even to functions) aren't treated the same. If you ever come to work on a system where pointers of different kind really are different, you will know it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: “I doubt you find a modern system where it won't work”: You are likely thinking about whether it “will work” or “will not work” based on the representations of the different types of pointers being the same. But that is not a valid basis for determining whether it will or will not work. Modern compilers make decisions based upon types and other factors. A compiler that sees some pointer of type `void *` being used may conclude it is a different object from a pointer of type `long *`…

Comment: … Code may or may not “work” in different circumstances depending on what is visible to the compiler and its optimizer. If the union is visible, the compiler is required by the C standard to support accessing `bar.entries` and determining its value by reinterpreting the bytes in the new type, so that will work if the representations are the same. However, if the elements are accessed in a context where the union definition is not visible, as where the members have been passed by pointer to some function, there can be issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I have a union that contains pointers to different types of data, would it be legal to free malloced memory via a different field than the one it was assigned to? Does it even match the "common initial sequence" rule?

- What you describe does not satisfy the criteria of the "common initial sequence" rule, as that is about union members that have structure types.  Pointers are not structures.
- Even if we were talking about structures containing pointers as members, pointers types are not compatible if their pointed-to types are not compatible.  `void` and `long` are not compatible types, and probably `Foo` is not compatible with either, so the common initial sequence rule would not apply even if you wrapped the pointers in structures.
- In C, you do not need to rely on the common initial sequence rule to read a different union member than was last written.  In practice, it is very common for implementations to use the same representation for all object pointer types, and on such implementations, you probably could use any of those pointer members to free the pointed-to data.  HOWEVER, C does not *require* all object pointer types to use the same representation, and there have historically been implementations in which they didn't.  On one of those, the practice you describe most likely would not reliably behave as you intend.  Such code can conform to the language spec, but it does not conform *strictly*.  It is not portable.

Answer (score 1):

> Do pointers to different types match the "common initial sequence" rule?

No.

> would it be legal to free malloced memory via a different field than the one it was assigned to?

In the context of the question, is `free(bar.entries)` valid?

I would say this falls into implementation dependent. When you read a different union member that was assigned, the memory is interpreted as the new type. Now, it *may happen* that when you reinterpret that memory storing a `long *` as a `void *`, you will get a proper address which will point to the same `long *`, in which case `bar.entries == bar.long_entries`. Or it may not happen. Or you might get a trap representation.

*In practice*, the code will work on normal architectures, as normal architectures have all pointer types represented in assembly the same.